# How to remove all cells with single char pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this df:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Number' : ['one', 'two', '-', '-', 'five'],
                    'Color' : ['-', 'red', 'blue','yellow', '-']})
---
  Number        Color
0    one-five       -
1    two         red
2      -         blue-black
3      -         yellow
4   five           -
```

I would like to replace with " " (empty space) all cells that contain a specific character ("-" in this case) but only if there is only this char in the cell
For exaple:

```
      Number     Color
0    one-five       
1    two         red
2                blue-black
3                yellow
4   five
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this the `replace` function in pandas replace the exact `string` matching not like `str.replace`

```
df1.replace("-","",inplace=True)
```

Comment: a thousand thanks!